# Redirect with connect-flash message when trying to access route when not logged in

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, connect-flash

I would like to redirect to the login page with an error message, when someone tried to access my admin page without authenticating, ie when someone tries to bypass the login page.

this is my `admin` end point:

```
server.get('/admin', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    console.log('Trying to access admin section')
    res.render('admin', {
        user: req.user //get the user out of session and pass to template
    })
});
```

which contains the following `isLoggedIn` middleware:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
   console.log('Someone is trying to access this page without being authenticated')
    req.flash('loginMessage', 'You need to be authenticated to access this page');
    console.log(req.flash('loginMessage'))
    res.redirect('/login')
}
```

the `login` access point is defined as the following:

```
server.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Using login route');
    res.render('login',
        {message: req.flash('loginMessage')}
        );
});
```

My problem is, when someone tries to access the `admin` page directly, the flash message doesn't show up.
However when trying to login with fake credentials, the error messages do show up in the login page.
For information, this is how my post login route is set up:

```
server.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect:'/admin', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect:'/login', //redirect back to the login page if there is an error
    failureFlash: true //allow Flash messages
}));
```

And I get the following messages in the terminal:

```
Someone is trying to access this page without being authenticated
[ 'You need to be authenticated to access this page' ]
GET /admin 302 8.859 ms - 68
Using login route
GET /login 200 79.373 ms - 1930
```

Comment: Right now, can a user not authenticated can access the admin page ?

Comment: No, a user not authenticated can not access the admin page. My problem is not with the authentication, it's with passing a connect-flash message to my redirect.

Comment: Are you able to display flashes by using other simple routes ? For example set a flash at '/setflash' and redirect it to '/flash' and view it there.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment, when I put a wrong password in the login page or i login with a user name that is not already in the db (ie registered), I do have the correct flash messages being displayed, same for instance if i am on the register page and I use an already used login, flash messages are being displayed.

Comment: Okay I just wanted to know if you have setup flash properly, since there wasn't any other places where you are using it in the code (except passport's, thought it had a different flash, but i was wrong when I checked it).

Comment: That did the trick! I tend to use `console.log` a lot to debug my applications, did not think of this possibility. Do you want to answer the post instead of commenting, so I can give you the stackoverflow points for it?

Comment: Yeah sure ! Glad that you cared to :).

Comment: Okay I'm deleting the answer parts from the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In connect-flash, when you are retrieving the flash messages set on a key with `req.flash(<key>)`, it copies the messages of the `<key>` to a temp array, DELETES the messages for that `<key>` from the connect-flash's internal flash message store and then returns that temp array.

So the `flash('loginMessage')` returns empty at route '/login', because you have previously retrieved it at `isLoggedIn`'s `console.log(req.flash('loginMessage'))`.

I found it when I checked the sources of connect-flash. Its here : [flash.js of connect flash](http://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash/blob/master/lib/flash.js). The exmples in there should give you the idea quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is coming to this and the selected answer doesn't work, consider trying the following. I've had the same issue but wasn't "consuming" the key at any stage using console.log etc.

The problematic version of the code was as follows. I called these instructions in a POST route:

```
req.flash('errorMessage', errors.array().map(err => err.msg););
res.redirect('/profile');
```

Where the GET route for 'profile' renders an EJS template with `errorMessage: req.flash('errorMessage')` among its inputs.

What worked for me was assigning my error messages (`errors.array().map(err => err.msg)`) to a variable and passing that variable to connect-flash, like so:

```
var errMsgs = errors.array().map(err => err.msg);
req.flash('errorMessage', errMsgs);
res.redirect('/profile');
```

Hope this helps.